# Implementing AsyncQueryHandler

Tags: android, android-handler

I am trying to implement `AsyncQueryHandler` because I am experiencing the same exact problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604914/contentprovider-insert-always-runs-on-ui-thread) but I dont see any example or anything about implementing it.

I tried doing

```
AsyncQueryHandler handler = new AsyncQueryHandler(getContentResolver());
```

since that is what the constructor shows in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) but I get an error saying `cannot instantiate the type AsyncQueryHandler` so how do I use it then?

Comment: Good place to start would be the AOSP source code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) is an abstract class, thus you cannot instantiate it directly. You need to subclass it.

Answer (score 17):

It's so convenient:

```
AsyncQueryHandler handler = 
    new AsyncQueryHandler(mActivity.getContentResolver()) {};
handler.startUpdate(-1, null, sessionUri, values, null, null);
```

Comment: I get this warning when I try to do it `This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur`

Answer (score 12):

It comes very handy when you need to do CRUD operationa async without using a Loader,  so by extending from asyncquery you get  method such as [startQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html#startQuery%28int,%20java.lang.Object,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29), [startInsert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html#startInsert%28int,%20java.lang.Object,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues%29), [startUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html#startUpdate%28int,%20java.lang.Object,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) and [startDelete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html#startDelete%28int,%20java.lang.Object,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) an easy implementation could be:

```
public class CustomAsyncHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {

        private WeakReference<AsyncQueryListener> mListener;

        public interface AsyncQueryListener {
            void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor);
        }

        public CustomAsyncHandler(ContentResolver cr, AsyncQueryListener listener) {
            super(cr);
            mListener = new WeakReference<AsyncQueryListener>(listener);
        }

        public CustomAsyncHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
            super(cr);
        }

        /**
         * Assign the given {@link AsyncQueryListener} to receive query events from
         * asynchronous calls. Will replace any existing listener.
         */
        public void setQueryListener(AsyncQueryListener listener) {
            mListener = new WeakReference<AsyncQueryListener>(listener);
        }

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
            final AsyncQueryListener listener = mListener.get();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onQueryComplete(token, cookie, cursor);
            } else if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see there is an extra interface AsyncQueryListener created to be as a callback when query is completed, as this you can create AsyncUpdateListener, AsyncDeleteListener, AsyncInsertListener, and so on.

Comment: Why would you not want to use a Loader when doing CRUD operations?

Comment: Because loader are not meant for CRUD operations!

Comment: As AsyncQueryHandler already has its own onQueryComplete() method, why is there any need to use AsyncQueryListener?

Comment: The extra listener interface is because you need to propagate the event back to the instantiating class.

Comment: simple and elegant, 10x, but why using WeakReference? no potential  memory abuse in this case..

Comment: @gor If you use this class as static inner class, then WeakReference will be in handy.

Comment: The WeakReference goes beyond "memory abuse" and helps protect you from situations where the calling class has been destroyed before you get the query result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 AsyncQueryHandler asyncQueryHandler = new AsyncQueryHandler(activity.getContentResolver()){

        @Override
        protected void onInsertComplete(int token, Object cookie, Uri uri) {
            super.onInsertComplete(token, cookie, uri);
            Log.d(TAG, "onInsertComplete  return uri: " + uri);
        }

 };

 asyncQueryHandler.startInsert(-1, null, mUri, values);
```