# AsyncQueryHandler onQueryComplete Confusion

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have found two different methods for implementing `AsyncQueryHandler`:

1. [One on the stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13354862/1773155)
2. Second on [this](http://www.seal.io/2013/02/how-to-use-asyncqueryhandler_20.html?showComment=1367036741909) blog.

In the first method we are not subclassing from `AsyncQueryHandler` while in the second method we are manualy closing the `cursor`.

**I want to know that**

Does `AsyncQueryHandler` not handle `cursor`? or we must close it manually (as done in the second method)?

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncQueryHandler`, as seen in the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.java), does **not** handle any returned `Cursor` that is returned in `onQueryComplete`. Note that any of the other `ContentProvider` methods (insert, update, delete) do not return a `Cursor` and are therefore much easier to understand.

Generally, if you are going to query a `ContentProvider` and use the resulting data (to say, fill a `ListView`), you would want to use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) along with a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html). These classes are available in the support library and provide a much more robust framework (including automatically reloading data if the underlying `ContentProvider` data changes) for managing queries.

Comment: The problem with `CursorLoader`s is that they are only made for loading `Cursor` from the DB using `ContentProvider`, I want to preform `Insert/Delete/Update` using `AsyncQueryHandler`. I dont want to use `AsyncTask` because `AsyncQueryHandler` is made specially for Asynchronous DB operations using ContentProviders.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal - so what's your question? For Insert/Update/Delete `AsyncQueryHandler` is perfect and what is recommended for simple operations and there's no `Cursor` to close/not close in those cases.