# How to implement AsyncQueryHandler?

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous, android-contentprovider

I am learning AsyncQueryHandler. Is there any Example or demo available which can describe this properly. I have seen some example which were taken from some project. But that was not that clear. I was looking more of a sample project which is implementing this concept. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is unclear with that class?

Comment: Curd Operations. I need a simple demo of curd operations

Answer (score 0):

There is question about this topic with example in comments: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961857/implementing-asyncqueryhandler)

Also you should realize that AsyncQueryHandler is an abstract class, so you need to create class that extends AsyncQueryHandler and override (at least) its unimplemented methods.

Comment: no,  its no abstract class,  but yes,  without extending it, ACH is helpless

Comment: It is an abstract class, Description is given here [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html)

Comment: hmm, i could swear it wasnt abstract when i was reading its docs, but yes you are right, it is.

Comment: Anyways have you got any demo which can explain curd operations.