# ProgressDialog not shown in AsyncTask

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a huge database (40MB) on an SDCard. I need fetch data, with `LIKE` in query, which is very slow.

DB request takes about 5 seconds. Therefore, I need to do it asynchronously and with `ProgressDialog`.

I tried it with `AsyncTask`, but problem is with `ProgressDialog`.
 It was implemented this way:

```
private class GetDataFromLangDB extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(TranslAndActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

         urDBCursor.close();
         curDBCursor = null;
         scaAdapter = null;

         this.dialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
         this.dialog.show();

    } 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... whatSearch) {
        String result = "";

        if (myDatabaseAdapter != null) {
            curDBCursor = myDatabaseAdapter.fetchAll(whatSearch[0]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }

            prepareListView();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `ProgressDialog` is not shown during the DB request.
After finished database query, it flash on screen for a short time. When user tries
to tap on screen during database request, UI is freezed, and after DB request
message about 'not responding' is shown.
I tried it with a thread this way:

```
public void startProgress(View view, final String aWhatSearch) {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        if (curDBCursor != null){
            curDBCursor.close();
            curDBCursor = null;
        }

        dialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        dialog.show();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                curDBCursor = myDatabaseAdapter.fetchAll(aWhatSearch);
                // dirty trick
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(250); // it must be here to show progress
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        prepareListView();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
```

The result was the same, but when I used the trick with  `Thread.sleep(250)`; 
 `ProgressDialog` was shown during the database request. But it is not spinning,
 it looks freezed during the DB request.

DB stuff is called this way (after tap on search button):

```
btnSearchAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // AsyncTask
        new GetDataFromLangDB().execute(edtTextToSearch.getText().toString());

        // or Thread 
        //startProgress(null, edtTextToSearch.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

I found a lot of problems like this in SO, but nothing was useful for me.
 Could it be that DB is on SD Card?

Comment: DB is on SDcard is not the reason for this . Can you paste the part of code from where you are calling the AsyncTask .

Comment: Calling code is quite simple - button clicked, updated

Answer (score 1):

I put the definition of the dialog into the AsyncTask Class and it works fine for me.
Take a look at this exampel (You have to change NAMEOFCLASS in the name of your CLASS:

```
private class doInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

   final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(NAMEOFCLASS.this) {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.daten_wait_titel));
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dse_dialog_speichern));
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
```

....

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                   // DO YOUR UPDATE HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
                }

}
```

Comment: I think that his definition of the dialog is in AsyncTask. He reference it by using this.dialog

Comment: Yes definition of the dialog is in the AsyncTask. Therefore I'm confused what's wrong there. Maybe during the heavy DB load -> device is not responding due to the busy SQLite driver.... **Maybe I need service for this (?) **

Comment: Ok. that's right. Then the only diference is the line Super.OnPreExcecute(); Perhaps it will help to delete this line.

Comment: @Peter And could you give us the logcat?

Comment: @JackTools.Net  If he deletes super.OnPreExecute it will definitely crash the application

Comment: Well I use the exampe I posted several times and it works fine  for ne without this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604914/contentprovider-insert-always-runs-on-ui-thread) could help you. It looks like similar problem. Try to use [AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) for querying your database

Answer (score 0):

declare you Dialog box on Class (Activity) level like this

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
```

show the progress dialog and call the **AsyncTask** class when you want to start you Busy work..like onButton click or any

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Sending Email to your account please! wait...", true);
SendingEmailTask task = new SendingEmailTask();
String s = "";
task.execute(s);
```

create your inner class like

```
private class SendingEmailTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         //do your work here..
         // like fetching the Data from DB or any
         return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
           //hide progress dialog here
           dialog.dismiss();
       }
}
```

let me know if this help!!

Comment: thanks for an answer, but it did not help. It still the same. I will try sinisha answer with AsyncQueryHandler, or I try to wrap it into  a **Service**

Comment: okay i didn't check with DB loading so not sure about that but i do this for sending email etc and it works fine with me..well good luck with AsyncQueryHandler