# Why is my code running on the main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm using the following code in my onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9002);
                            Socket s = serverSocket.accept();

                            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                                    s.getOutputStream());
                            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                            outputStream.write("Howdy! newbie".getBytes());

                            s.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.run();
            }
        });
    }
```

It gives me a NetworkOnMainThreadException!

It does work when I use the following lines to remove the restriction:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

But why should I use it?

I used thread, why isn't it running on the separated thread and runs on the UI thread?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
thread.run();
```

to

```
thread.start();
```

**Difference:**

> **Thread.run()** does not spawn a new thread whereas **Thread.start()**
>   does, i.e `Thread.run` actually runs on the same thread as that of the
>   caller whereas `Thread.start()` creates a new thread on which the task
>   is run.

For more info see [Difference between running and starting a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841301/difference-between-running-and-starting-a-thread)

Comment: Thanks! It was a great mistake!

Comment: @MTP1376 Happy to help,don't forget to accept,anyway enjoy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not asking the thread to start.

Replace:

```
thread.run();
```

With

```
thread.start();
```

Calling `run()` will simply execute the provided `Runnable` on the current thread. However, `start()` will spawn the execution onto a new thread.

Comment: Hahaahaaaaaaaaaa :)))
Tnx :)))

Comment: @MTP1376 you should have selected this guy's answer because it does a better job of explaining what goes on:  .start() is the method that the Java library provides to start a thread.  .run() is the (tragically named) method that _you_ provide that tells the thread what to do.

Answer (score 2):

### Change from `thread.run()` to `thread.start()`

---

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9002);
                                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();

                                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                                        s.getOutputStream());
                                BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                                outputStream.write("Howdy! newbie".getBytes());

                                s.close();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }
            });
        }
```