# Interesting Thread behavior in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I was learning the concept of Multithreading in Java where I came across this very interesting behavior. I was experimenting with various ways of creating a thread. The one under question now is when we are extending a `Thread`, not implementing the `Runnable` interface.

On a side note, I am aware that it makes perfect OO sense to implement the `Runnable` interface rather than to extend the `Thread` class, but for the purposes of this question, let's say we extended the `Thread` class.

Let `t` be my instance of my extended `Thread` class and I have a block of code to be executed in the background that is written within my `run()` method of my `Thread` class.

It perfectly ran in the background with the `t.start()`, but I got a bit curious and called `t.run()` method. The piece of code executed in the main thread!

What does `t.start()` do that `t.run()` doesn't?

Comment: I believe you can find your answers here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841301/difference-between-running-and-starting-a-thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134221/3436942 tells you the difference in easy - enough language. Pretty much **t.start();** is making /creating a new thread whilst **t.run();** merely calls it on the main thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is what the class does. The t.start() will actually start a new thread and then calls run() in that thread. If you directly invoke run() you run it in your current thread.

```
public class Test implements Runnable() {
    public void run() { System.out.println("test"); }
}

...

public static void main(String...args) {
    // this runs in the current thread
    new Test().run();
    // this also runs in the current thread and is functionally the same as the above
    new Thread(new Test()).run();
    // this starts a new thread, then calls run() on your Test instance in that new thread
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
}
```

This is intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The `t.start()` simply does what it says: starts a new thread, that executes the `run()`'s portion of code. `t.run()` is a function call on an object, from the current working thread (in your case, main thread).

Just keep in mind: only when call `start()` function of a thread, a new thread is started, otherwise, calling it's functions (other than `start()`) is the same as calling a plain function on any other different object.

Answer (score 0):

`t.start()` makes a native call to actually execute the `run()` method in a new thread. `t.run()` merely executes the `run()` in the current thread.

Now,

**On a side note, I am aware that it makes perfect OO sense to implement the Runnable interface than to extend the Thread class**

Actually, it makes *perfect* OO sense to follow either approaches (implementing Runnable or extending Thread). It is not that one is bad in OO sense. The advantage that you get by *implementing Runnable* is that you can make your class *extend* another class (which *might* actually break your OO design.)

Comment: s/main thread/current thread/, AFAIK.

Comment: I was speaking with respect to current context. If you are planning to add features and functionalities to a `Thread`, then it makes sense to extend the `Thread` class. If you just want to create a new thread, implement the `Runnable` class. :)

Comment: @DarkDust - I am not getting you.

Comment: Anyway, the main advantage of implementing Runnable is that in that case you are not extending Thread, therefore you don't inherit all the Thread class's baggage, which you could unintentionally involve (call/override/mutate) in your implementation code.

Comment: It makes sense to extend Thread when you want to make a new _kind_ of Thread object.  (If you wanted to override Thread.join() or Thread.setName() for example.)  But, a Thread object is not a thread:  It's an object that _manages_ a thread.  Q: Does the object that manages a thread waiting for network clients have different responsibilities from the one that manages a thread running background tasks?  Certainly the threads themselves have different responsibilites, but the Thread objects?...  Not so much.